# ASP.Net Web API returning 500 internal Server Error when iTextSharp namespace included in ApiController.cs file

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-applications, itext, internal-server-error

ASP.Net Web API returning 500 internal Server Error when iTextSharp namespace included in ApiController.cs file.
Other API's which are declared in other controller which does not iTextSharp namespace are working perfectly. Please help.

Exact Message it returns "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

It is working perfectly on localhost but not when I deployed it on server.

Also I cannot capture this error in Application_Error()

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurred because of the font used for `iTextSharp` having incorrect path. Please check font Path.